# AJAX data not displayed in page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

To sum up what I'm trying to achieve here:

- Inside of `index.php`, when selecting an option in a dropdown list, a function is called with the `onchange="displayData(this)` event inside of `<select>`
- This function performs an AJAX `POST` request to a PHP page (`target.php`) with the `value` of the selected option inside of `data`
- The PHP page is displayed inside a `div` on the page

Here is the function, using jQuery:

```
function displayData(str){
  $.ajax({
    url: "target.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"value": str.value},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  $('#my-div').load('target.php');
}
```

To make things easier, here is what the PHP page looks like: `<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>`

When logging `data` on `success`, everything seems to work fine, the value of `$_POST['value']` is displayed in the console correctly. In the page itself though, I get an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: value

Sorry if it seems kind of dumb, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... So I thought of asking the community. Thank you for your help guys! Cheers.

---

Comment: ` $('#my-div').load('target.php');` this is call and load your view again perform and you are reading value `<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>`

and jquery load function perform get method.

Comment: `$.ajax` and `.load` both is a way to fetch data from the server .. So no need to use both of them in your case.. Buta if you passing `value` with `.load` you need to use `$_GET['value']` .. It'll be better to take a look at [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.
and you need to return the result from `target.php` page

```
function displayData(str){
  $.ajax({
    url: "target.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"value": str.value},
    success: function(data){
      $('#my-div').html(data);
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use .load() your browser will make another GET request to target.php and display it, so your $_POST will be empty.
You can use `$('#my-div').html(data)` inside success: of ajax or you can use $_GET instead of $_POST in your php and pass variable in url like this

`$('#my-div').load('target.php?value='str.value);`

Answer (score 0):

hey the problem is quite simple, if you are posting the data value getting from ajax to target.php then the  **$('#my-div').load('target.php')** should be inside the ajax success function and you have to put the data using html function like this **$("#my-div").html(data)**. it will directly load the data in html format inside the div.